# Calculate Balances in a ledger query for Specific account?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write my first database.

My problem is with calculating the *Account* balance in each row for a single account.  I tried `DSUM` but it messed up every time.

The table contains both columns for *amount due* and *payments*.

In my query I want a new column, `Balance`, that would show the **cumulative** difference of `AmountDue` and `AmountPaid` for an account in each row.

I know basic SQL but i am not an advance user.

I tried `DSUM()` to calculate sums of amounts but it shows sums of all rows together not for every single row.

My table is `CreditorTransactionsT`:

- `TransID`, `TranaDate`, `CustomerAccount`, `AmountDue`, `AmountPaid`

the new query would look like:

- `TransID`, `TranaDate`, `CustomerAccount`, `AmountDue`, `AmountPaid`, `Balance`

Comment: Is `TransID` an autonumber field - i.e. can we assume that `TransID` will be lower for the previous payment from the same `CustomerAccount`.  Failling that will there only ever be one payment on a single day from a `CustomerAccount`?  To get the cumulative amount you need to know the previous payment - the order of rows in the table is irrelevant in a database.

Comment: yes. TransID is autonumber. and sorted in ascending order. the balance should sum all [AmountDue] - [amountPaid] till the current [TransID].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table looks like this:

```
| TransID | TranaDate  | CustomerAccount | AmountDue | AmountPaid |
|---------|------------|-----------------|-----------|------------|
| 1       | 01/12/2018 | ABC             | £15.00    | £10.00     |
| 2       | 01/12/2018 | DEF             | £20.00    | £5.00      |
| 3       | 02/12/2018 | DEF             | £30.00    | £10.00     |
| 4       | 02/12/2018 | ABC             | £50.00    | £5.00      |
| 5       | 03/12/2018 | ABC             | £10.00    | £15.00     |
| 6       | 04/12/2018 | ABC             | £5.00     | £10.00     |
```

Then this SQL:

```
SELECT  T2.TransID
        , T2.TranaDate
        , T2.CustomerAccount
        , T2.AmountDue
        , T2.AmountPaid
        , SUM(T1.AmountDue) AS TotalDue
        , SUM(T1.AmountPaid) AS TotalPaid
        , SUM(T1.AmountDue) - SUM(T1.AmountPaid) AS Balance
FROM    CreditorTransactionsT T1 INNER JOIN CreditorTransactionsT T2 ON T1.TransID <= T2.TransID AND
                                                                        T1.CustomerAccount = T2.CustomerAccount
GROUP BY T2.TransID
        , T2.TranaDate
        , T2.CustomerAccount
        , T2.AmountPaid
        , T2.AmountDue 
ORDER BY    T2.CustomerAccount, T2.TranaDate
```

will return this table:

```
| TransID | TranaDate  | CustomerAccount | AmountDue | AmountPaid | TotalDue | TotalPaid | Balance |
|---------|------------|-----------------|-----------|------------|----------|-----------|---------|
| 1       | 01/12/2018 | ABC             | £15.00    | £10.00     | £15.00   | £10.00    | £5.00   |
| 4       | 02/12/2018 | ABC             | £50.00    | £5.00      | £65.00   | £15.00    | £50.00  |
| 5       | 03/12/2018 | ABC             | £10.00    | £15.00     | £75.00   | £30.00    | £45.00  |
| 6       | 04/12/2018 | ABC             | £5.00     | £10.00     | £80.00   | £40.00    | £40.00  |
| 2       | 01/12/2018 | DEF             | £20.00    | £5.00      | £20.00   | £5.00     | £15.00  |
| 3       | 02/12/2018 | DEF             | £30.00    | £10.00     | £50.00   | £15.00    | £35.00  |
```

Comment: Thank You very Much. but just one thing please. this query would not open in design view without messing up the code. is their a way to run this using a parameter [Enter Customer Account:] so it would show the balance for a single customer only?

Comment: Your question used `TranaDate` rather than `TransDate` (I thought it a bit strange at the time, but went with it) - make sure all field names are correct as per your table (off now, so most likely won't be able to respond until January).

Comment: corrected the field names. query runs just fine. but shows balances for every account. can you help me with adding a parameter that would ask the user to **[Enter Customer Account:]** an show balances for that customer only?

Comment: Add as the first line `PARAMETERS AccountNum TEXT(255);` then between the `FROM` and `GROUP BY` lines add `WHERE T2.CustomerAccount = AccountNum`

Comment: You can probably change `AccountNum` to `[Enter Customer Account:]` in my previous comment.

Comment: From your first comment - you won't be able view the query in design view because Access can't show the `<=` as a join.

Comment: it gave the error. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables. would making  another query that takes data from this query and  gives single account's records affect  Performance? And thank you very much. you can't think how much you have helped me. its the first database of my life and its about to get completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a calculated field in your query, it can do simple sums like that and is ideal if you don't want to keep the results outside of your query:

https://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut02.htm

Something like:

Balance: [AmountDue]-[AmountPaid]

Comment: just tried this. but it shows the difference if current row. but not cumulative balance. It should add the previous balance to the difference in amounts.